# Regular expression for extracting the prefix of a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a c# regular expression for extracting the prefix of a string which has a postfix of 2 characters and a number.

**I MUST USE REGEX**

example:

> input: "ABCDZZ4321"
>
> output: "ABCD"

I want to cut the two 'Z' characters and the number at the end.

Another example:

> input: "ABCD4R4321"
>
> output: "ABCD"

Comment: Could you show what you have been trying so far?

Comment: sure:
var pattern = @"^(.*)(?=.{2}\d+)";

Comment: You should definitely state your requirements better in future. People are giving answers that apparently don't apply to you.. because you haven't stated that you _must_ do this in Regex (except for in comments to answers).

Comment: Is the first part always 4 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with Regex:

```
var result = "ABCDZZ4321".Split('Z')[0];
```

EDIT:

Regex version.. even though its highly overkill:

```
var match = Regex.Match("ABCDZZ4321", @"^(\w+?)([A-Z0-9]{2})(\d+)$");
var result = match.Groups[1].Value; // 1 is the group.. 0 is the whole thing.
```

Regex is fixed now. As far as I can tell.. this will work for your requirements.

Comment: I have to do it in regex

Comment: OP want from `2Z` not the single one

Comment: @AmitAgrawal It doesn't matter. You split on a single Z disregarding the rest. The result is the same.

Comment: No If requirement is from `2Z` then result will differ

Comment: Regex has been updated.

Comment: "Why bother with Regex" - because he's been told to use regex for his homework & he can't be bothered to learn regex's.

Comment: @DavidArno You might note that I answered way before the OP mentioned that. Also, I was the one telling the OP to include this in their question.

Comment: @Simon, my apologies: I wasn't trying to criticise you or suggest you didn't already know this. I was more venting my frustration at this sort of question.

Comment: My apologies too. I didnt read your entire comment. Might be bed time for me I think!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would do?

```
^(\w+?)\w{2}\d+$
```

In-depth explanation:

- ^ = match the beginning of the string.
- \w = match any non-whitespace character(s)
- \w+ = match *one or more* of these
- \w+? = match *one or more*, in a "non-greedy" way (i.e. let the following match take as much as possible, which is important in this case)
- \w{2} = match two non-whitespace characters
- \d+ = match *one or more* digit character
- $ = match the end of the string

(I used [this site](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to test the regexp out while writing it.)

Also, if you only need to match A-Z, you can replace \w with [A-Z]; it seems more appropriate in that case.

Comment: Hehe, lots of people answering this during the few minutes when I wrote my answer. :)

Comment: Thing is, the 2 characters can be anything including digits, so in case of "ABCD4R4321" your regex fails...

Comment: @user2866008 Please put these requirements in your question then.

Comment: @user2866008: actually, it doesn't. :) \w = any non-whitespace character. Digits aren't whitespace, so my solution works for these cases also. (but the suggested [A-Z] does not of course)

Comment: When I used Regex.Match(input, pattern) it gave the solution in Group[1]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `^\w{3,}\d+$`. This would locate any strings that begin with at least 3 chars (2 that you need in the middle and 1 so that you have something to return) and that ends with some set of digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this regex: `(.*?ZZ)` and then remove ZZ or replace whit ""

Answer (score 0):

Then even like this.

```
var input = "ABCDZZ4321";
var zzIndex = input.IndexOf("ZZ");
var output = input.Substring(0, zzIndex);
```

Regex is definitely an overengineering here

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"^(.+)ZZ\d+$", "$1")
```

Explanation: 
all what comes at start of string will be catched in the group 1 (round parenthesis). In the replacement patterns it will be referenced with '$1'.
Greet you OP from the community ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the string.LastIndexOf()

```
string input = "ABCDZZ4321";
string splitOn = "ZZ";
string result = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(splitOn));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code. I have tried with "ABCDZZ4321" and long input string in below code. In both tests it's giving required result "ABCD".

```
string input = "ABCDZZ455555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555321";
            Regex rgx = new Regex("(?<content>.*?)[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]+");    
            Match MatchResult = rgx.Match(input);

            string result = string.Empty;
            while (MatchResult.Success)
            {
                result = MatchResult.Groups["content"].Value;
                break;                
            }
```